# ServiceNow REST API endpoint for on-call employees

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api, servicenow-client-scripts

I am looking for an endpoint on the ServiceNow REST API to GET a list of my team's currently on-call employees, with their email addresses.

I have found a lot of info but may be missing something in the ServiceNow docs. I am trying to use the "REST API Explorer" as described on [this page](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/vancouver-api-reference/page/integrate/inbound-rest/task/t_GetStartedAccessExplorer.html), but do not see the "System Web Services" section under "All" in ServiceNow.

For context, I need this endpoint for a python script in Splunk, a custom alert action that would send alert emails only to the currently on-call employees. Thus the need for this list from ServiceNow, which has the info on on-call employees.

Any and all help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember how I originally found it, but I have been using the following method:

```
GET /api/now/on_call_rota/whoisoncall?group_ids={{sys_id}}&date_time={{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}}
```

```
[
  {
    "memberId": "119f399173062300e7af6238edf6a7e7",
    "memberIds": [],
    "userId": "62826bf03710200044e0bfc8bcbe5df1",
    "userIds": [],
    "roster": "9d9f399173062300e7af6238edf6a7e5",
    "rota": "349f399173062300e7af6238edf6a75e",
    "group": "096fb59173062300e7af6238edf6a783",
    "escalationGroups": [],
    "deviceId": "",
    "deviceIds": [],
    "isDevice": false,
    "order": 1,
    "isOverride": false,
    "rotationScheduleId": "119f399173062300e7af6238edf6a7df",
    "memberScheduleId": "9d9f399173062300e7af6238edf6a7ec"
  },
  {
    "memberId": "1d9f399173062300e7af6238edf6a7e8",
    "memberIds": [],
    "userId": "a8f98bb0eb32010045e1a5115206fe3a",
    "userIds": [],
    "roster": "9d9f399173062300e7af6238edf6a7e5",
    "rota": "349f399173062300e7af6238edf6a75e",
    "group": "096fb59173062300e7af6238edf6a783",
    "escalationGroups": [],
    "deviceId": "",
    "deviceIds": [],
    "isDevice": false,
    "order": 2,
    "isOverride": false,
    "rotationScheduleId": "119f399173062300e7af6238edf6a7df",
    "memberScheduleId": "d99f399173062300e7af6238edf6a7ef"
  }
]
```

The *date_time* parameter needs to be in UTC time.

This REST call loosely conforms to the Server API call found in the [official documentation](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/vancouver-api-reference/page/app-store/dev_portal/API_reference/OnCallRotation/concept/c_OnCallRotationAPI.html#title_OCR-whoIsOnCall_S_S_S_GDT), so it may also support those additional parameters. I tried some of the other Server APIs at that REST endpoint, but they weren't valid.